# How to use google docviewer in an MVC application to read doc files?

Tags: asp.net-mvc, asp.net-mvc-3, api, asp.net-mvc-4, google-api

How to use google docviewer in an MVC application to read doc files?

```
 <iframe src="http://docs.google.com/viewer?url=http%3A%2F%2Flocalhost%3A3907%2FContent%2FBullettin%2FJCI.pdg&embedded=true"></iframe>
```

but it doesn't show up WHy?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

You could embed it in an `<iframe>`. For example if you wanted to view the following document http://crypto.stanford.edu/DRM2002/darknet5.doc you would have an iframe like that:

```
<iframe src="http://docs.google.com/viewer?url=http%3A%2F%2Fcrypto.stanford.edu%2FDRM2002%2Fdarknet5.doc&embedded=true"></iframe>
```

The `viewer` endpoint accepts 2 parameters: `url` and `embedded`.

Comment: Thank u Darin..But how should I generate url=http%3A%2F%2Fcrypto.stanford.edu%2FDRM2002%2Fdarknet5.doc&embedded=true"?. In my MVC the docs are saved in Content folder of the application. S how should I genrate my URL?

Comment: Like that: `<iframe src="http://docs.google.com/viewer?url=http%3A%2F%2Fexample.com%2FContent%2Fmyfile.doc&embedded=true"></iframe>`. This will display the `http://example.com/Content/myfile.doc` file from your website.

Comment: I have given it as  <iframe src="http://docs.google.com/viewer?url=http%3A%2F%2Flocalhost%3A3907%2FContent%2FBullettin%2FJCI.pdg&embedded=true"></iframe> but it doesn't show up WHy?

Comment: Maybe because the `http://localhost:3907/Content/Bullettin/JCI.pdg` address is not accessible from the internet. In order for Google Doc to work the document must be accessible from the internet.

Comment: So can we make it accessible , as I am on the development stage.

Comment: No, I think you will have to host it somewhere. After deploying it will be alright assuming that the location is publicly accessible.